# Approach to Polar Change of Variable in $\int_0^ {ae^{{\pi}/4}} \int_{2 \log(r/a)}^{\pi/2} f(r, \theta) r dr d \theta$.

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

> $$\int_0^ {ae^{{\pi}/4}} \int_{2 \log(r/a)}^{\pi/2}  f(r, \theta) \ r \ dr \ d \theta$$

In the above integral, for evaluating and sketching it, I have to change the order of integral, but I am not able to get the right approach. Is there any  general method to handle change of order of integration in polar coordinates?

The answer is $\theta$ varies from $0$ to $\pi/2$ and $r$ varies from $a$ to $ae^{\theta/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever seen a general method to handle change of order in such integrals in (between) any coordinates. In this example we have $2\ln\dfrac{r}{a}\leq \theta\leq\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $r\geq0$ hence
$$\color{red}{0\leq r\leq ae^{\frac{\theta}{2}}}$$
and also
$$0\leq r\leq ae^{\pi/4}$$
this makes an annulus and gives restriction $0\leq \dfrac{r}{a}\leq e^{\pi/4}$, taking $\log$ of sides, then
$$-\infty\leq \ln\dfrac{r}{a}\leq \dfrac{\pi}{4}$$
or $-\infty\leq 2\ln\dfrac{r}{a}\leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}$ gives bound for $\theta$
$$\color{red}{-\infty\leq \theta\leq \dfrac{\pi}{2}}$$
finally your integral is
$$\color{blue}{\int_{-\infty}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{ae^{\frac{\theta}{2}}}f(r,\theta)r \ \mathrm{dr} \ \mathrm{d\theta}}$$

Comment: sorry the answer given is different. How did u get area in negative region. Can you plot the two graphs.

Comment: The answer "The answer is θθ varies from 0 to π/2π/2 and rr varies from a to aeθ" is false. I'll give you an example

Comment: $a=1$, $f=1$, then $$\int_0^ {ae^{{\pi}/4}} \int_{2 \log(r/a)}^{\pi/2}  f(r, \theta) r  dr d \theta=\dfrac12e^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Comment: while $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\int_{a}^{ae^{t/2}}  f(r, \theta) r  dr d \theta=-\frac12\pi-\frac12+e^{\frac{pi}{2}}$$